# Which ports to open on host firewall so that network printing and scanning works?

Tags: networking, firewall, printing

I have a multi-functional machine which is both a laser printer and a scanner (Samsung SC-4705ND)

I am not able to make the scanner work with the (software) firewall installed in my computer turned on. Operating system is ubuntu 12.04 with regular firewall.

if firewall is turned off then everything works as expected

I run nmap to discover open services on the samsung machine and I opened all these ports:

```
80, 427, 515, 631, 5200, 9100, 10001
```

but with not luck..

How should I configure firewall?

Comment: Are you restricting ingress only, or also egress?

Comment: run wireshark while printing and scanning... that should tell you what's what... or.. see other answer..

Comment: Thank you. I used wireshark and I got various communication between pc address and printer/scanner address with main port 1514, but still nothing consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitelist the MFC by IP? If you've opened outgoing traffic to it, it may well be some sort of PoS (well, more of a PoS than we already established it to be) that isn't going to stick to a consistent set of ports... also opening a load of ports to everyone seems overkill.

Comment: Well I guess there is no need to search any further. As you suggested I simply whitelisted all traffic on all ports both TCP and UDP, FROM the ip of the printer/scanner TO the ip of the pc. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you've got the mfc on a static IP - that could be a source of annoyance after a power outage otherwise :)